# regex, repeating part of expression

Tags: regex

I wonder how can I improve my expresssion to check everything in one expression  instead of create a lot of rules.

here is my expressions

```
/from-([^/]+)-([^/]+)/
/from-([^/]+)-([^/]+-[^/]+)/
/from-([^/]+)-([^/]+-[^/]+-[^/]+)/
```

I would like check phrase: from-Country-city or from-Country-city-city or from-Country-city-city-city

Comment: Remove the `/` from start/end and split with `-`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match and what do you want to capture?

Comment: We'll need at least an example of what you're trying to check to be able to help.

Comment: Is the only stipulation that there can't be a forward slash between the hyphens? It still isn't clear what exactly you want to match, and if you want to capture any part of the match. If "country" and "city" have to be alphabetic, then `from(-[a-zA-Z]+)+` should do the job. Since your included regexs only care about "not forward slash", then that suggests `from(-([^\/]+))+`. If there's more to this, please include it in your question.

Comment: I wrote rewrite-rules for my WP plugin, its my rule`'offer-details/([^\/]+)/from-([^\/]+)-([^\/]+)/to-([^\/]+)-([^\/]+)/(\w+)-([^\/]+)/id/([^\/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=offer-details&load_type=$matches[1]&loading_country=$matches[2]&loading_city=$matches[3]&unloading_country=$matches[4]&unloading_city=$matches[5]&truck_body=$matches[6]&load_weigh=$matches[7]&id=$matches[8]',`
sometimes I got city where name contain "-" character. To service correct city with "-" I wrote extra condition  when i added `-[^/]+`

Comment: `sometimes I got city where name contain "-" character`. This is a problem, since there is no way to tell if it is a separator or part of a city name.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this expression satisfies your requirements:

```
from-(\w+)-([\w-]+)
```

Here is a live example/demomstration: https://regex101.com/r/gF0fS2/1

The meaning of the expression:

1. Match the literal string `from-`
2. followed by one or more word characters, defined as group 1 `(\w+)`
3. followed by the literal string `-`
4. followed by one or more of the set of word characters or the dash, defined as group 2 `([\w-]+)`

For more information on regular expressions, please see these websites:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/ Comprehensive reference
- https://regex101.com/ Tool for trying and testing your own expressions